# Display image in ngFor in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a very similar problem as described here, but unfortunately none of the solutions provided in the answers work for me. I am trying to display an image inside ngFor in one of my Ionic views.

Here's the code:

```
  <div
    class="activities__elem-img"
    [ngStyle]="{
      'background-image':'url(http://mybackend.com/' + item.node.image ? item.node.image.key : 'notfound' + ')'
    }"
  ></div>
```

Unfortunately, style is not shown in the DOM. However, this code works with other CSS properties, like `background-size`. How can I display an image?

All I see in my HTML code is this: `ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"`. I expect I'd see an URL leading to my image.

EDIT: Works as suggested in comment, but does not work when I put it in function:

```
[ngStyle]="{
  'background-size': 'contain',
  'background-image': getImageUrl(item)
}
```

And my function:

```
getImageUrl({ node }) {
  const imageUrl = `http://my.backend.com/${node.image ? node.image.key : "notfound"}`;
  return `url ( '${imageUrl}' )`;
}
```

Comment: When you inspect the generated HTML, is the URL what you expect?

Comment: You should put parentheses around the conditional operator: `... + (item.node.image ? item.node.image.key : 'notfound') + ...`.

Comment: In your modified question, make sure to pass the correct parameter to the function: `getImageUrl(item.node)`.

Comment: It's passed. I even logged the result from the function to the console and it seems to be OK

Comment: But you pass `item` and your method expects `item.node`. Also, you may try to remove the inner quotes on the last line of the method.

Comment: Because I am using ES6 destructuring here

Comment: If the result of `getImageUrl` is OK, the only difference that I see is the inner quotes and the spaces that are not present in the template code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `+` operator has higher [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than the `?:` operator, your expression is equivalent to:

```
('url(http://mybackend.com/' + item.node.image) ? item.node.image.key : ('notfound' + ')')
```

You should put parentheses around the conditional operator:

```
'url(http://mybackend.com/' + (item.node.image ? item.node.image.key : 'notfound') + ')'
```